# How to Create Auto Fill Macro in Excel Based on a Table in Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, tracker

I have Sheet2 with raw data and I need to autofill Sheet1 depending on the Sheet2 data.

Logic
1. test EditorName(Col A) from Sheet2 to Sheet1
2. Check AUDIT TYPE(Col G) in Sheet2 to know which table to fill
3. Check Tier(Col B) to know which column in table above in Sheet2 to fill
4. Get Points(Col F) per row and fill Sheet1 column(Depending on Logic 2 & 3)

I have manually added the first 2 entries for reference.

I'm a bit noob in programming. I tried to create a new table with unique Editor Names and hope to go from there but hard a big time mental block on what to do next. I have to logic but not the programming knowledge.

*Sheet 1 Tracker Main Sheet (Destination)*
[image]

*Sheet 2 Raw Data (Source)*
[image]

```
Sub Fill_Tracker()

    Dim WSS As Worksheet
    Dim WSD As Worksheet

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Temp"
    Set WSS = Sheets("RAW")
    Set WSD = Sheets("Temp")

    WSS.Range("A1", WSS.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy WSD.Range("A1")

    With WSD
        .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        .Cells("B1").Value = "Tier"
        .Cells("C1").Value = "AUDIT TYPE"
    End With

    MsgBox "Done", vbOKOnly, "Message"         

End Sub
```

Comment: You've got your logical steps sorted out which is a good start.So you need to loop through each item in sheet2 and do some stuff, which consists of checking two cells. You could use the Find method. Or if you don't have many audit types you could predefine, i.e. if New Doc go to column I, and then check the type. Those merged cells might end up being a nuisance though.